# i want to replace using dom please

Tags: php, dom, xpath, replace, preg-replace

**html code**

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
 <script type="text/javascript">
 function test() {
  //...
 }
 </script>
 <table class=eee>
 <tr>
 <td>{$my_name}</td>
 <td>{$my_name}</td>
 <td>{$my_name}</td>
 </tr>
 </table>
 <div class=aaa>
    <ul>{$member}</ul>
     <li><img src="test1.com">{$good_list} </li>
     <li><img src="test2.com">{$good_list} / {$regdate}</li>
     <li><img src="test3.com">{$good_list} / {$regdate}</li>
 </div>
 <ul class="aaa">
 <li>{$good_list}</li>
  <li>{$good_list}</li>
 </ul>
 <div class="bbb">
         <li>{$user_name}</li>
 </div>
 <ul class='ccc'>
  <li>{$board_list}</li>
  <li>{$board_list}</li>
  <li>{$board_list}</li>
 </ul>
 <div class=ddd>
 <ul>
  <li>{$board_list}</li>
  <li>{$board_list}</li>
  <li>{$board_list}</li>
 </ul>
 </div>
 <ul class='hhh'>
  <li>{$regdate}</li>
  <li>{$regdate}</li>
  <li>{$regdate}</li>
  <li>{$regdate}</li>
  <li>{$regdate}</li>
 </ul>
 <div class="aaa">
   <li><img src="test.com">{$good_list} / : {$regdate}</li>
   <li><img src="test.com">{$good_list} / : {$regdate}</li>
   <li><img src="test.com">{$good_list} / : {$regdate}</li>
 </div>
 <div class='zzz'>
 <table>
 <tr>
  <td>num</td>
  <td>subject</td>
  <td>wdate</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>{$num}</td>
  <td>{$list}</td>
  <td>{$regdate}</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>{$num}</td>
  <td>{$list}</td>
  <td>{$regdate}</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>{$num}</td>
  <td>{$list}</td>
  <td>{$regdate}</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>{$num}</td>
  <td>{$list}</td>
  <td>{$regdate}</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>{$num}</td>
  <td>{$list}</td>
  <td>{$regdate}</td>
 </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

**i want to replace**

**result**

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<script type="text/javascript">
 function test() {
 //...
 }
</script>
<table class=eee>
 <tr>
 <td>{$my_name[0]}</td>
 <td>{$my_name[1]}</td>
 <td>{$my_name[2]}</td>
 </tr>
</table>
<div class=aaa>
   <ul>{$member}</ul>
    <li><img src="test1.com">{$good_list[0]} </li>
    <li><img src="test2.com">{$good_list[1]} / {$regdate[1]}</li>
    <li><img src="test3.com">{$good_list[2]} / {$regdate[2]}</li>
 </div>
 <ul class="aaa">
  <li>{$good_list[0]}</li>
  <li>{$good_list[1]}</li>
 </ul>
 <div class="bbb">
   <li>{$user_name}</li>
 </div>
 <ul class='ccc'>
  <li>{$board_list[0]}</li>
  <li>{$board_list[1]}</li>
  <li>{$board_list[2]}</li>
 </ul>
 <div class=ddd>
 <ul>
  <li>{$board_list[0]}</li>
  <li>{$board_list[1]}</li>
  <li>{$board_list[2]}</li>
 </ul>
 </div>
 <ul class='hhh'>
  <li>{$regdate[0]}</li>
  <li>{$regdate[1]}</li>
  <li>{$regdate[2]}</li>
  <li>{$regdate[3]}</li>
  <li>{$regdate[4]}</li>
 </ul>
 <div class="aaa">
   <li><img src="test.com">{$good_list[0]} / : {$regdate[0]}</li>
   <li><img src="test.com">{$good_list[1]} / : {$regdate[1]}</li>
   <li><img src="test.com">{$good_list[2]} / : {$regdate[2]</li>
 </div>
 <div class='zzz'>
 <table>
 <tr>
 <td>num</td>
 <td>subject</td>
 <td>wdate</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>{$num[0]}</td>
 <td>{$list[0]}</td>
 <td>{$regdate[0]}</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>{$num[1]}</td>
 <td>{$list[1]}</td>
 <td>{$regdate[1]}</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>{$num[2]}</td>
 <td>{$list[2]}</td>
 <td>{$regdate[2]}</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>{$num[3]}</td>
 <td>{$list[3]}</td>
 <td>{$regdate[3]}</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>{$num[4]}</td>
 <td>{$list[4]}</td>
 <td>{$regdate[4]}</td>
 </tr>
 </table>
```

**i want to this result**

I have struggled day and night to solve this problem, but I did not solve it in the end. Please need your help.
I would appreciate your help.

In each class area, we want to transform the sub-codes according to the class name.

It would be nice if you could use xpath, query, and getElementByTagName to get the output, but you can use other methods as well.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an XSLT 3.0 solution:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
  version="3.0">
  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:template match="text()[normalize-space()]">
    <xsl:variable name="var" select="replace(., '^\{\$' || '([a-z_]+)' || '.*$', '$1')"/>
    <xsl:variable name="n">
      <xsl:number level="any" start-at="0" 
           count="text()[starts-with(.,'{$' || $var)]" from="*[@class]"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:value-of select="replace(., '\{\$([a-z_]+)\}', 
      '{\$$1[' || $n || ']')"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It requires the input to be well-formed XML, you may need to run a tidy utility on your existing HTML to achieve that.

Comment: You can invoke XSLT stylesheets from PHP. Support for XSLT 1.0 is built-in, support for XSLT 2.0/3.0 requires installation of the Saxon/C library. You can of course solve the problem using native PHP code as well, but it will probably be 100 lines of code rather than a dozen, because XSLT is designed explicitly for XML transformation.